# Error when attempting to change a relationship from a lookup to a master/detail in sandbox

Tags: metadata, master-detail

> Cannot add a master/detail relationship because the division and/or owner fields are in use: DatasetData: null

What sort of metadata is "DatasetData"?  It sounds related to WaveDataset, but I believe I've cleaned all the Wave metadata up - as nothing there seems to reference the OwnerId field anymore.

I've done a number of successful dry runs of this in scratch orgs, but obviously those are pretty pristine compared to a sandbox.

*Edit: I turned OFF analytics completely in the sandbox and the error is still happening. So much for that hunch?*

Comment: Hi Did you cleaned the recycle bin some metadata stays there and get counted

Comment: I hadn't tried that - but when I did it didn't make a difference.  The error persists.

Comment: It's just a guess, but check whether there is a cross-object formula that relies on the existing field.  Sometimes formula errors are very strangely worded.  You can also use the "Where is this used?" button on the field to see where it's referenced.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SF Support helped me resolve this issue.  I was barking up the right tree with Analytics. It appears that even though I disabled data sync, it didn't actually remove the underlying configuration for the object I was changing the relationship on.

We re-enabled Data Sync then we removed the field from the sync definition and saved it. Once that was done I was able to change the relationship to Master-Detail.